# Decompositing Sobolev Norms on Subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

**Notation:**
Let $\Omega = \Omega_1\cup\dots\cup \Omega_n$ be disjoint open bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Let $\|\cdot\|_{k,\infty:A}$ be the Sobolev norm given by
$$
\|u\|_{k,\infty:A} \triangleq \max_{|\alpha|\leq k} \|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{\infty}},
$$
where $u$ is $k$-times weakly differentiable on $A$, and $A$ is a stand-in for any of the sets $\Omega,\Omega_1,\dots,\Omega_n$.

What is the relationship between $\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega}$ and $\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_1},\dots,\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_n}$?

---

**Hypothesis:**

What I (think) I have is that
$$
\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega} \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n \|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}
$$

---

**Reasoning:**

Is my reasoning correct?  Something is bothering me about it...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega}  & = \max_{|a|\leq k}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{|a|\leq k}\max_{i=1,\dots, n}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega_i} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{i=1,\dots, n}\max_{|a|\leq k}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega_i} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{i=1,\dots, n}\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega}  & = \max_{|a|\leq k}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{|a|\leq k}\max_{i=1,\dots, n}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega_i} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{i=1,\dots, n}\max_{|a|\leq k}\operatorname{ess-sup}_{x \in \Omega_i} \|D^{\alpha} u\|\\
& = \max_{i=1,\dots, n}\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}.
\end{aligned}
$$
is correct with the exception of the last equality, which is wrong.

But your hypothesis is correct, because the inequality
$$
\max_{i=1,\dots, n}\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}.
$$
holds.

In my opinion, the best description of
$\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega}$ is
$$
\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega}  
=
\max_{i=1,\dots, n}\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i}
=
\|(\|u\|_{k,\infty:\Omega_i})_{i=1}^n\|_{\ell^\infty},
$$
where we used the $\ell^\infty$ norm on $\Bbb R^n$.